# Python stopped working while opening with giving an exception handling error

Tags: python-3.x

"Unhandled exception at 0x0000000059937341 (pythoncom36.dll) in python.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction. occurred" This  is appearing while debugging it in visual studio.

Comment: May be an issue with SSE2/AVX instruction support on the CPU/OS.

Comment: No @Anaksunaman it was working fine before and it was throwing this error when i tried to debug it